# Getting installed printers in .Net Maui

Tags: printing, maui, maui-windows

I am trying a to get a list of installed printers in my net maui app targeted for windows.

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
namespace MauiApp2;
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;
    public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    la.Text = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count.ToString();
}
}
```

I tried adding the system.drawing.common reference to the project.

```
    <ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.Drawing.Common">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\6.0.13\System.Drawing.Common.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

And get a list of installed printers using printersettings.installedprinters.
My project is targeted for windows. Am I doing it wrong? Or is there some other way to do it?

Edit:
I updated the code to the following:

```
#if WINDOWS
    public string GetPrinterNames()
    {
        
        try
        {
            x= PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
           
        }
        return x;
    }
#endif
```

Still it crashes and shows this code in app.g.i.cs file:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Edit: system.drawing.printing is not supported for .Net Maui with target .net 7. I got the solution to work for now with target .net 6

Comment: Please show us what you tried and explain what specific problem or error you are having

Comment: I edited the question to add the code. And it gives no error. Just crashes.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: What exception causes the crash?  Either add exception handling or use the debugger to view the exception

Comment: Edit the question with further updates. Still crashing. I don't know enough about exception handling or how to use debugger to view the exception

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022